# Can you enchant your other characters' gear?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The question might answer itself by just thinking about it......
But is it at all possible to create an enchanter character, and send it my other characters' soul-bound gear just to get enchanted?
If not, that means the only way you can get your gear enchanted is if you actually run into an enchanter and do it via the trade window.  Correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** Before Wrath of the Lich King was released, the only way to enchant someone else's gear was to have them place it in a trade window -- which meant you couldn't use an enchanter alt to put enchantments on your main character's gear, and selling enchantments involved advertising in trade chat and meeting people face-to-face. (The horror!)

WotLK (via the Inscription profession) added [enchanting vellum](http://www.wowpedia.org/Vellum), which an enchanter can place an enchantment on to "store" it for later use. You can then send it to your alt or even list it on the auction house. To use it you just right click it like you would a scroll, then click on the gear you want to enchant.

Comment: Awesome -- I heard about the scrolls, but I didn't know they were of actual enchants.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note: Enchanting Vellums can be bought at vendors... they used to be Inscription created only, although Inscriptionists can still create them.  (They also used to specifically be Weapon Vellum or Armor Vellum, but that went away)

Comment: @Powerlord -- Inscriptionists isn't a word; Use "scribe" or "scrivener" instead!